# Finding intersections between line segment and general polygon in 2D/3D

Tags: python, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm trying to use the CGAL python-bindings to write a program (in Python) to find intersections between 1 object (which could be a line segment(s) or a polygon/polyhedron) and another polygon/polyhedron. While I am currently working in 2D, I would like to extend the program to 3D as well.

I've installed the python-bindings for CGAL already. I understand it is still under development, but it seems it can already do a lot of things. I have managed to get it to output intersections between a line segment and a tetrahedron (using the AABB tree algorithms), and intersecting sequences of dD iso-oriented boxes. However, the AABB tree algorithms seem to only work with 3D objects. I guess I can represent my general shape as a pseudo-3D object, but then I ran into the problem of actually constructing the 3D object. The examples given in the python-bindings only work for tetrahedrons, and I cannot figure out how to create a general polyhedron. So my problem has become two-fold:

1. How do I define a general polyhedron using the CGAL python-bindings?
2. How do I use the defined polyhedron to calculate intersections and distances from other general shapes like line segments and polygons?

So for a tetrahedron, the package does (from https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/blob/master/examples/python/AABB_polyhedron_facet_intersection_example.py) :

```py
from CGAL.CGAL_Kernel import Point_3
from CGAL.CGAL_Polyhedron_3 import Polyhedron_3

p=Point_3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
q=Point_3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
r=Point_3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
s=Point_3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
polyhedron = Polyhedron_3()
polyhedron.make_tetrahedron(p, q, r, s)

#constructs AABB tree
tree = AABB_tree_Polyhedron_3_Facet_handle(polyhedron.facets())

#constructs segment query
a = Point_3(-0.2, 0.2, -0.2)
b = Point_3(1.3, 0.2, 1.3)
segment_query=Segment_3(a,b)
```

This creates a tetrahedron, which can support queries on intersection, squared distance etc. However, this does not work for more than 4 points. In my case, the polygon/polyhedron would be defined by around 50 points. How do I create such an object using CGAL-python?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the efficiency of the program.
You can try my latest python package Geometry3D by

```sh
pip install Geometry3D
```

As it is written in pure Python, it's a little slow and is not suitable for works like graphics.
But it works well in common situations and it supports many geometries.

An example is shown below

```py
>>> from Geometry3D import *
>>>
>>> a = Point(1,1,1)
>>> b = Point(-1,1,1)
>>> c = Point(-1,-1,1)
>>> d = Point(1,-1,1)
>>> e = Point(1,1,-1)
>>> f = Point(-1,1,-1)
>>> g = Point(-1,-1,-1)
>>> h = Point(1,-1,-1)
>>> cph0 = Parallelepiped(Point(-1,-1,-1),Vector(2,0,0),Vector(0,2,0),Vector(0,0,2))
>>> cpg12 = ConvexPolygon((e,c,h))
>>> cpg13 = ConvexPolygon((e,f,c))
>>> cpg14 = ConvexPolygon((c,f,g))
>>> cpg15 = ConvexPolygon((h,c,g))
>>> cpg16 = ConvexPolygon((h,g,f,e))
>>> cph1 = ConvexPolyhedron((cpg12,cpg13,cpg14,cpg15,cpg16))
>>> a1 = Point(1.5,1.5,1.5)
>>> b1 = Point(-0.5,1.5,1.5)
>>> c1 = Point(-0.5,-0.5,1.5)
>>> d1 = Point(1.5,-0.5,1.5)
>>> e1 = Point(1.5,1.5,-0.5)
>>> f1 = Point(-0.2,1.5,-0.5)
>>> g1 = Point(-0.2,-0.5,-0.5)
>>> h1 = Point(1.5,-0.5,-0.5)
>>>
>>> cpg6 = ConvexPolygon((a1,d1,h1,e1))
>>> cpg7 = ConvexPolygon((a1,e1,f1,b1))
>>> cpg8 = ConvexPolygon((c1,b1,f1,g1))
>>> cpg9 = ConvexPolygon((c1,g1,h1,d1))
>>> cpg10 = ConvexPolygon((a1,b1,c1,d1))
>>> cpg11 = ConvexPolygon((e1,h1,g1,f1))
>>> cph2 = ConvexPolyhedron((cpg6,cpg7,cpg8,cpg9,cpg10,cpg11))
>>> cph3 = intersection(cph0,cph2)
>>>
>>> cph4 = intersection(cph1,cph2)
>>> r = Renderer()
>>> r.add((cph0,'r',1),normal_length = 0)
>>> r.add((cph1,'r',1),normal_length = 0)
>>> r.add((cph2,'g',1),normal_length = 0)
>>> r.add((cph3,'b',3),normal_length = 0.5)
>>> r.add((cph4,'y',3),normal_length = 0.5)
>>> r.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a3ko.png)

You can also look at the documentation [Geomrtry3D](https://github.com/GouMinghao/Geometry3D)